# Does EC2 have a rate limit? It seems if you use AB to test the request we get throttled

Tags: amazon-ec2

We have 25 instances with one load balance on Ec2. If we hit any single one the speed is fast(<300ms) but if we us AB to test multiple connections we get poor results often with an average of 1800ms.  Does anyone know if this is EC2 limiting us, we're only hitting these servers from 27 outside servers with about 2 million requests and hour so maybe they think it's a DOS?

Comment: Hi Ryan.  Are you using an Elastic Load Balancer, or a software-based load balancer?

Comment: If it is software based, Network throughput may be the issue.  I don;t know the performance statistics on the ELBs, although it seems like they may be open to the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

We've loaded tested applications with up to 2.8 million requests with an average round trip latency of under 100ms. Based on this, and the fact that you're using slightly fewer requests, I doubt you're being throttled.

Having said that, this question was asked in 2009 (over 2 years ago at the time of writing), so it's entirely possible that AWS was doing things differently back then.